# Erro ao compilar projeto xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estou tendo esse erro:

> A tarefa "XamlCTask" não foi instanciada de
>   "C:\Labs\FCM-Xamarin-Forms-master\FCM\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' ou uma de suas dependências. Operação sem
>   suporte. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131515) FCM

Isso aconteceu ontem, quando eu baixei o projeto. Tentei e nada. Hoje pela manhã, fui tentar rodar e funcionou. Bem, criei o projeto no Firebase e quando fui rodar novamente, veio a mensagem. Não mexi em nada, nem quando funcionou e nem agora, deixei da forma que que baixei. Esse projeto tem várias classes e vou postar a classe MainActivity do Droid:

```
[Activity(Label = "FCM", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static MainActivity instance = null;

        // Return the current activity instance.
        public static MainActivity CurrentActivity
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            instance = this;
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            try
            {
                // Check to ensure everything's set up right
                GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
                GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);

                // Register for push notifications
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Registering...");
                GcmClient.Register(this, PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS);
            }
            catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog("There was an error creating the client. Verify the URL.", "Error");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(e.Message, "Error");
            }
        }

        private void CreateAndShowDialog(String message, String title)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.Create().Show();
        }
    }
```

Qualquer ajuda para resolver esse caso é bem-vinda.

Comment: Tentativas: Tentei adicionar manualmente essa referência, mas deu outros problemas. Removi e deixei como deveria ser.

Comment: Existem atualizações para fazer dos pacotes, mas não consigo devido ao erro.